# Error when trying to assign blob object

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

The following code

```
for h in hits:
    urls.append(h['url'])
    result = db.Blob(urlfetch.Fetch(h['url']).content)
    model.image = result
```

returns the error

> cannot concatenate 'str' and
>   'NoneType' objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use some debug printing to find out if `urlfetch.Fetch(h['url']).content` is even returning anything.  Based on the error, the result is `None` and `db.Blob()` is expecting the result to be a string.

If so, plan accordingly by checking the value of `content` before trying to apply it.  And maybe a little error tracking for good measure?

Here's a simple example:

```
errors = []
for h in hits:
    urls.append(h['url'])
    content = urlfetch.Fetch(h['url']).content
    if content is not None:
       result = db.Blob(urlfetch.Fetch(h['url']).content)
    else:
       print 'No content for', h['url']
       errors.append(h)
       continue

    model.image = result
```

Answer (score 0):

I see concatenation only on this line:

`urls.append(h['url'])`

judging by error: 'String' would be urls, and 'NoneType' would be h['url']
Most likely h['url'] is empty. Make sure of this by printing it to console.

Comment: Strings in Python don't have an `append` method - `urls` is clearly intended to be a list.